# Inertia Tensor of an ellipsoid

Tags: integration, volume, tensors, tensor-decomposition

Given is the following inertia tensor of a certain mass distribution $\rho(\vec{r})$ :

$$ I_{ij} = \int dV \rho(\vec{r}) \left( \vec{r}^2 \cdot \delta_{ij} - r_ir_j \right) $$

I should compute the inertia tensor for the following ellipsoid: 
$$x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 \le 1$$

And I'm allowed to use $\rho(\vec{r}) = \rho_0$, and I should then give the result as a function of the mass $M$.

It's clear to me how I parameterize the Ellipsoid and how to compute the Jacobian, but I don't get how I should integrate that expression.

Comment: _Hint:_ can you show that $I$ will be diagonal?

Comment: @Fabian as long as only one component of $\vec{r}$ is not equal zero, while the others are, the tensor will be diagonal right ? and now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the parametrization

\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& a r \sin\theta\sin\phi \\
y &=& b r \sin\theta\cos\phi \\
z &=& c r \cos\theta
\end{eqnarray}

with $0<r<1$, $0<\theta<\pi$ and $0<\phi<2\pi$. The Jacobian for this choice of coordinates is $abc r^2\sin\theta$, so the integral becomes

\begin{eqnarray}
I_{ij} &=& \rho_0\int{\rm d}r~{\rm d}\theta~{\rm d}\phi ~ abc r^2\sin\theta [\underbrace{r^2\left(\sin^2\theta\left(a^2\cos^2\phi+b^2\sin^2\phi\right)+c^2
\cos^2\theta\right)}_{x^2+y^2+z^2}\delta_{ij} - x_i x_j] \\
&=& \frac{3M}{4\pi} \int{\rm d}r~{\rm d}\theta~{\rm d}\phi ~ r^2\sin\theta [r^2\left(\sin^2\theta\left(a^2\cos^2\phi+b^2\sin^2\phi\right)+c^2
\cos^2\theta\right)\delta_{ij} - x_i x_j]
\end{eqnarray}

where I used $\rho_0 = 3M/(4\pi a b c)$. Now it is a matter of integrating, for example

\begin{eqnarray}
I_{11} &=& \frac{3M}{4\pi} \int{\rm d}r~{\rm d}\theta~{\rm d}\phi ~ r^2\sin\theta [r^2\left(\sin^2\theta\left(a^2\cos^2\phi+b^2\sin^2\phi\right)+c^2
\cos^2\theta\right) - a br^2\sin^2\theta\sin\phi\cos\phi] \\
&\cdots& \\
&=& \frac{M}{5}(b^2 + c^2)
\end{eqnarray}

This is the result you should get

$$
{\bf I } = \frac{M}{5}\begin{pmatrix}
b^2+ c^2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & a^2+ c^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a^2+ b^2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: why did set $\rho_0 = \frac{3M}{4\pi}$ ? and why did you multiply the Jacobian by $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ ??

Comment: @Leroy I assumed the density is constant $\rho = M / V = M / (4\pi a b c 
 / 3)$. I didn't multiply the Jacobian by $x^2+y^2+z^2$, just replaced the expression ${\bf r}^2\delta_{ij} - x_i x_j$

Comment: Why are all other entries in the matrx $0$ ??

Comment: @Leroy Short answer: symmetry. But if you want to convince yourself you will need to calculate the integrals, it is not too complicated, just a bunch of trigonometric functions

Comment: as far as inertia tensors are concerned, can I just assume the $-x_i x_j$ part will always be cancelled out by the integral ?

Comment: @Leroy What happens actually is that the integral goes to zero, and that's different to assuming that the ${\bf r}^2\delta_{ij} - x_i x_j = 0$